# HP LaserJet P1006 won't print after power off/on

Tags: printing, hp

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with an HP LaserJet P1006 connected by USB cable.  On both this new installation and on a previous hard drive, the HP LJ P1006 would run until it's power was turned off.  Upon restarting the printer, the printer would not print.  (The system produces a message that the document has been printed, but the jobs remain in the queue.) In the previous installation, I had a Windows dual boot, and, if I exited Linux, booted Windows and printed, the P1006 would work and then would work on restarting Linux.  Restarting Linux without getting the printer to work on Windows does not affect (the lack of) printing.  I still have toner, so I'd appreciate any help.  I ran the debugger, and got the message that it was unable to solve the problem.  I can upload the results, but they're voluminous.

Thank you.

Comment: The P1006 requires a plugin from HP. Have you installed it?

Comment: I did on the previous install. The problem appeared after (but not necessarily because of) an Ubuntu update. I’ll look at the HP website again. As I recall, HP sends you to an outside download repository.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is obligatory. Its installation is at

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2032909#p2032909.

More detail at

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2030960#p2030960.

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  Before I saw your response from yesterday, I reinstalled hplip (actually an updated version: 3.21.4) from the HP link to the Linux download/installation website.  The plugin was part of the installation, and the printer is now working and power off/on doesn't cause trouble.  Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue for setting up printer HP P1006 in Ubuntu 22.04

```
$ hp-plugin

Checking for network connection...
Downloading plug-in from: None
error: Plugin download failed with error code = 8
error:  file does not match its checksum. File may have been corrupted or altered
```

Solved by this answer
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/552897-Hplip-plugin-checksum-error

```
cd
wget https://developers.hp.com/sites/default/files/hplip-3.22.6-plugin.run -O hplip-3.22.6-plugin.run
wget https://developers.hp.com/sites/default/files/hplip-3.22.6-plugin.run.asc -O hplip-3.22.6-plugin.run.asc
hp-plugin --plugin=~/ -i
```